# Kafka - How to store events indefinitely?

Tags: apache-kafka

What are the kafka **Broker** settings/values to keep kafka events in store indefinitely?

The following are the two suspects with their values:

- log.retention.ms=-1
- log.retention.bytes=-1

Are the above settings all I need? Are the values correct?
Documentation of the broker settings didn't mention anything about indefinite values.

I am using Kafka v2.2.0 in Confluent v5.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct, to disable the retention limits you have to set these 2 settings to `-1`.

The broker settings are not explicit about these special values but both the corresponding [topic configurations](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) mention `-1` as unlimited.